# What does the tie across other different notes mean?

Tags: guitar, notation, sheet-music, rhythm

There are two ties in the bass part of the following excerpt for a Drop D guitar part. Both of them include some other different notes. According to the tie's definition, 16th note + 8th note = 3/16th note.

In the case of the first tie, should I play a 3/16th note at the beginning of the second measure, or shall I play a whole 3/8th note?

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't do this myself.  It's more accurate to write out the entire note value, in this case a quarter note.  In fact, since this is 6/8 time, I would just use a dotted quarter note here and get rid of the tie altogether.  In both cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way this is written is just incorrect. You can guess what it means: you have to hold the base note while you play the other notes. But I insist: the way it's written is just wrong; it is not an acceptable notation. In these cases you just write the base note with its correct duration as a different voice.

**[EDIT]** A correct way of writing this:
[image: Written musical excerp]

**[EDIT]** Another way, for guitar, etc.:
[image: Written musical excerp]

Comment: Maybe the author used the software which only support two voices in a staff. Is it possible to represent it in just two voices? It would be much more helpful if you draw the correct way in a staff.

Comment: I added a correct way of writing this. I'm afraid there is no proper way to write it in two voices, because there are three.

Comment: Alternatively, George, since the original excerpt appears to have been written for guitar, it should remain on one staff (therefore the ledger lines are acceptable.) A proper way to write it in two voices would be to merely show a short tie coming off the bass voice of the grouping - this would complement the written directions of "let basses ring" from the original example.

Comment: I didn't think of the guitar. I edit the post by adding another example in one staff, that would be also correct.

Comment: While I agree that your suggested notations are often better, these are known as "Ravel ties" -- I've edited my answer with some examples.

Comment: @George The notation originally used is **not** wrong, just very unusual. In this case - two voices in one staff - your suggestion is indeed the preferred form. However, in the case of three or more voices on a single staff, the preferred form is using ties as in the example (which NReilingh calls Ravel ties), and will be generally understood among (classical) musicians. Furthermore, it may indicate a difference in musical intent: your notation indicates a distinct voice, the Ravel notation indicates notes that just happen to be longer than can be conveniently indicated.

Comment: What would you think of writing everything for the first three eighth-note beats of the second measure as four down-stem 16ths grouped with an eighth?  The first 16th note would include an "A" tied to the third 16th note, and the third 16th note would include a "D" tied to the eighth?  To my eye, from a timing perspective, the "A" is part of the 16th note phrase and would best be covered by the same beam.

Comment: @George actually there is a way. The lowest voice can be ommited, because these accompaniments are usually played by holding all the notes, I.e.  the second note should also be long.  --  but this clearly needs more knowledge then the person who wrote this seems to have.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I generally wouldn't write myself when typesetting or editing a piece of music, but is nonetheless an acceptable notation for piano music involving arpeggios.

You interpret it simply by ignoring the notated value of the first note except to figure out where the next note in the arpeggio should be. Just hold the note through the duration of the tie, playing the arpeggiated chord above it as written.

**EDIT:**

There seems to be some disagreement over the acceptability of this notation. Like I said, personally I would opt instead for something like what Beethoven does on the [second-to-last page of the Moonlight Sonata](http://www.youngcomposers.com/forum/uploads/1/8/1/8/11555.attach.jpg)), but in spite of the voice-rhythm inconsistency, the notion of tying an arpeggio to a chord is an accepted practice for chording instruments like piano, guitar, and harp.

They are known as **Ravel ties**, and you will see [questions](http://forum.makemusic.com/default.aspx?f=5&m=317684) [about](http://www.youngcomposers.com/forum/t13809/dumb-sibelius-question/) [them](http://forum.makemusic.com/default.aspx?f=5&m=63407) crop up often in community forums for notation programs like Sibelius and Finale, since they are generally not played back properly (in current versions of the software) without some extra tweaking. Lilypond, however, even goes so far as to include the example [in their documentation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/writing-rhythms#Selected-Snippets-18), and I'm certainly not going to argue with the wonderful engraving nerds that run *that* project!

Some real-world examples can be found all over Ravel's own [*Gaspard de la Nuit*](http://imslp.org/wiki/Gaspard_de_la_nuit_(Ravel,_Maurice)), alongside similar usage for grace-notes (possibly a more "readily accepted" usage), in the first and third movements in particular:

[image: First movement, bar 31] [image: First movement, last measure] [image: Third movement] [image: third movement, last measure]

Comment: It also has the comment "Let basses ring" to indicate this.

Comment: Agreed; I might have written a dotted eighth, with the moving line notated as sixteenth rest followed by the sixteenth and quarter.  There's really two moving lines plus a "pedal tone" in that measure.

Comment: Dotted quarter, not eighth, no?

Comment: @NReilingh - I respectfully disagree that this is acceptable notation - for piano or any instrument otherwise.  The durations of tied tones *must* correlate with the rhythms occurring during the tie.  The exception here is of course if there are two or more parts being portrayed in the same staff (such as trumpet I, trumpet II) and therefore have different music.  That said, if the parts are too different rhythmically, they must be notated on individual staves. In the case of the provided example, it should be notated as a 16th tied to a 16th tied to a 1/4 tied to 1/8 for maximum clarity.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes I would have said the exact same thing a year ago, but I ended up proving myself wrong with some extra research. I've elaborated on my answer with more information about this notation.

Comment: @NReilingh - Glad that you have done some research. However, French scores shouldn't be used as models for notation practices as they typically sport many nonsensical things.  Further, the chosen example is 106 years old and is not current with contemporary notational procedures.  Nice find though.

Comment: The notation in the original post, anyway, doesn't correspond to the "Ravel ties". In the examples you provided, the tied notes end up in a chord where all the notes have the same lenght. The original example has the first base note tied to an eighth note, which is nonsense, as the last note in the chord is actually a quarter note (not an eighth note).

Comment: @George The OP example could have put the chord on the quarter note as a D in octaves, but it would be at the expense of the single line that is created visually by those 5 notes. The tied-to eighth is in line with the last eighth in beat 1, so it is clear that the three-D chord is meant to be held up until that point. I would argue that the quality of being a "Ravel tie" does not hinge on the last note's chordedness, but on the duration of the first being shorter than what would usually be necessary to reach what it is tied to.

Comment: @NReilingh Of course we agree on the way to play it. But the tie in the first beat is not a "Ravel tie", it is just a mistake. The tie in the second beat is a "Ravel tie". See, for the notes involved, the rhythm in both beats is exactly the same, and the melodic sense is the same... and still they are written in two different ways. This is just wrong.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes Oh, no argument that the score in question is completely bonkers! But at the end of the day, the objective of notation is to communicate efficiently with the player, and this practice reduces clutter on the page while still being unambiguous… so despite Ravel's eagerness to break notational rules, I think we can say he wasn't doing it to make his scores harder to read. Anyway, this score was all I had access to; anecdotally, the practice seems to be a common occurrence in classical guitar music, but I would like to hear more from experienced classical guitarists on the matter.